# Реализация отправки смс-сообщений в Yii2

Tags: yii2, sms

Всем здравствуйте! Появилась потребность реализовать отправку СМС на телефон пользователя в проекте Yii2. Например, пользователь заполняют форму заявки, отправляет ее в работу, а ему приходит СМС о статусе заявки (в работе, выполнена).
Можно ли такое реализовать в Yii2, может были аналогичные примеры у кого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть сервисы на примере mainsms.ru, там взаимодействуешь с API, через которое отправляешь смс